# Best way to setup cross domain tracking between blog and e-commerce site?

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain

I run a blog that has an e-commerce site attached to it. I want to use a separate root domain for the e-commerce site to debloat the site but also want to continue being able to attribute what content leads to sales.

I hear that I need to implement both sites under the same Property View. Is this advisable or should I create a separate property view?

Also, my biggest concern is how do I identify traffic that is solely going to the e-commerce site without being referred to from the blog site? Is there a way of filtering this out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, the answer is "yes", by tracking everything in a Property (with the necessary setup), if a user lands on the blog from google search then he moves to the shop and buys, the sale will be organic.

For the second question, the answer is "you can see it with a segment". By creating a segment that excludes sessions (or users) who have seen the blog domain, you will only get those who landed and remained exclusively in the shop.